# No space left on device when moving 700k files to a single directory within the same FS

Tags: find, disk-usage, mv

I use the following command to find and move a huge number of files on my server:

```
find SomeDir/ -maxdepth 10 -type f -mtime +90 -exec mv {} SomeDir2/ \;
```

After moving about 700,000 files, I get this error:

```
mv: cannot move ‘SomeDir/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/file.jpg.gz’ to ‘SomeDir2/file.jpg.gz’: No space left on device
```

`df -i` has the following result:

```
/dev/sdb1           322125824 144163358 177962466   45% /files
```

`df -h` has the following result:

```
/dev/sdb1            4.8T  3.5T  1.1T   78%   /files
```

I do all the operation on `/files` and no other directories

The filesystem is `ext4`.

***UPDATE***

As suggested I run `dmesg -Hwx` and the out put is `EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_dx_add_entry:2016: Directory index full!`

Comment: Possibly some limit on the size of a directory. What FS is it? It's generally a bad idea to have millions of files in a single directory.

Comment: i use EXT4 on this server

Comment: `/files` is where `SomeDir2/.` resides, right?

Comment: Can you do `touch SomeDir2/newfile`? Is the part about `find` and `mv` relevant?

Comment: How many entries in `SomeDir2`? (`ls -AUq SomeDir2 | wc -l` assuming GNU ls)

Comment: See also `find SomeDir/ -maxdepth 10 -type f -mtime +90 -exec mv -t SomeDir2 {} +` (with GNU `mv` to avoid running one `mv` per file)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes they are all in /files


about 749093 entries

Comment: Not related to the actual issue, but you are aware that you're overwriting files that happen to have the same name as other files?

Comment: all files have different names @Kusalananda

Comment: `df -h SomeDir2` does return you the expected `/files` as the mountpoint, yes?

Comment: @roaima yes it does

Comment: You've not answered whether `touch SomeDir2/newfile` succeed or not. How about `mkdir SomeDir2/newdir` or creating files anywhere else in the same filesystem? Have you checked kernel logs (`dmesg` output)? What's the OS (distribution and kernel version)? Any default ACL on `SomeDir2`? Please add the information to the question ([edit] link), not in comments.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas pretty sure it fails. See my answer, I can reproduce this easily.

Comment: @AliGolestan if you run `dmesg -Hwx` while doing your moving, do you get any warnings?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes i can touch new files.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks marcus dmesg says `EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_dx_add_entry:2016: Directory index full!`

Comment: which version of the kernel are you running? (`uname -r`)

Comment: @MarcusMüller 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: oh, that is a nice vintage

Comment: fwiw maybe use `tar` to tar up all your files into one tar file, however big that may be, so that way its easier to preserve everything and move that around.  Of course it would likely not untar on your existing filesystem you would run into the same problem, but it's not hard to scrounge another disk these days and format it as xfs or something else; xfs can have 2^32 number of files in a directory.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably exceedingt `max_dir_size_kb` set (or left default) at mount time of the directory:

[Linux docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt):

> ```
> max_dir_size_kb=n
>     This limits the size of the directories so that any
>     attempt to expand them beyond the specified limit in
>     kilobytes will cause an ENOSPC error. This is useful in
>     memory-constrained environments, where a very large
>     directory can cause severe performance problems or even
>     provoke the Out Of Memory killer. (For example, if there
>     is only 512 MB memory available, a 176 MB directory may
>     seriously cramp the system's style.)
> ```

(`ENOSPC` translates to the error message `No space left on device` with `perror`)

So, make sure that option was not specified (or specified with a very large number) at mount time.

Also, remarks:

- too many files in one folder sounds like not a good idea. Do you maybe want a relational database instead? Object storage?
- 4.8 TB: that's not rare for modern hard drives, but honestly, next time you set something up in this day and age, use a storage pool like LVM. With that you can have things like snapshots of live systems.

Comment: the previous system admin did the storage stuff and as it seems he maybe had no idea about the LVM stuff.
there is no option specified for the mount point in the fstab

Comment: it's not *bad* it's not on LVM, it's just not convenient

Comment: @AliGolestan, you should be able to verify whether it's the root of the problem with `grep max_dir_size_kb /proc/self/mountinfo`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sadly, you can't: if you don't set the mount option explicitly, it does not show up in `mountinfo`, but it still fails.

Comment: On my system (ubuntu 20.04), on a 400M large device, `mkfs.ext4` creates a FS with `102400` inodes. Your test code creates one inode per directory entry, so that limit would be reached long before 1M files.

Comment: well, it does work with the `-o max_dir_size_kb=..` mount option! (that's why I shared that code: you can verify yourself.)

Comment: AFAICT, there's no limit by default in current versions of Linux, what's your version of Linux, mkfs or mount?

Comment: fedora 34, kernel 5.12.9, `libmount 2.36.2: selinux, btrfs, namespaces, assert, debug`, and mkfs.ext4 is from e2fsprogs 1.45.6

Comment: Your test case does the `cd /tmp/mymount` **before** mounting it the second time, so you'll be creating those files in the `/tmp` filesystem then.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oooooooh good catch!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and I was scratching my head, because `/linux/fs/ext4/namei.c`, line 60, is pretty clear on if you don't set that option, it shouldn't have an effect

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks! I was getting worried.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas judging by what I've just learned: hm, now I'm out of ideas. thing is, by moving, he's not significantly increasing the number of inodes, so it's not that he runs out of them. it's not the dir size. I'd guess OP would have told us if `dmesg` was shouting at him, but to be sure, I asked;  if anything in the dir checksumming etc ran out of space, there should have been a kernel warning.

Answer (score 1):

With the newly gained info:

So, reading linux/fs/ext4/namei.c line 2007 in git tag v3.10 (i.e., your kernel), I think you're kind of out of luck, and need to adjust your filesystem;

```
tune2fs -O large_dir /dev/sdb1
```

should allow you to have more `dx_entries` per directory, but honestly, I've never done that. As usual, have backups.

Make sure you've got backups, or apply this to a new filesytem where you copy these files to instead of moving them within the same file system. It might come across as if I'm an XFS fanboy (I'm not, it just works), but I think this really doesn't sound like an untuned ext4 is a great file system for this use case.

Comment: I can create a clone from this VM and test what you suggested. thanks

Comment: why clone the VM if you could just clone the file system you need?